# how to solve compile error : 2 type parameter expected for inline function

Tags: kotlin, generics, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

[image]

As above code, I want to pass only one generic type parameter like `number.on<Int> { }`.
But, compiler complains the error like attached picture. I think, In above code, complier may know type T because number is `Number` as receiver of `on`function. but it's doesn't.

Is there any solutions?

Comment: I do not suggest you to share your code as an image. Also you can use Any type to handle it and remove first parameter. I can not this answer question so I am sharing it in comments
`fun main() {     
        val number: Number = 2     
        number.on<String> { println(number) } } ​ 

inline fun <reified T> Any.on(function: (T) -> Unit): Any {     
        if (this is T) {
                 function(this)     
        }     
        return this 
}`